# manually deploy bitbucket git repo to a remote dev server

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have git setup locally(workstation) with a private repo hosted with bitbucket. I am experimenting with the way git does its thing, hence this question. How do I get the content held in the repo's master branch deployed to a remote dev server, so that the application can be tested by testers as I push the master branch to the bitbucket(origin) repo. I have read much about this on the internet, but not all has yet clicked together. I use sourcetree on a windows machine.

Regards,
Dion

Answer (score 0):

You can [`clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) a copy of the repo on the remote machine (or any machine) by logging into it (ssh, rdp, etc.), navigating to the directory you want to put the repo in, and running `git clone <repo>`. The URL to replace `<repo>` with will be specified in your bitbucket web UI.

The repo will then behave the same as the one on your local machine. Whenever you push a commit, your testers will be able to run [`git pull origin master`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) and receive the latest commits.

Comment: I found this url and started implementing it, but got stuck at  - cd ~/<repo-name>.git
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html/teachers.co.za git checkout -f master, with the error "error pathspec 'tts.git/master did not match any files known to git. " in essense, I want to work on my local machine, push commits to bitbucket, and from there have the development server updated automatically. The url I am using is - http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2013/11/19/automated-git-deployments-from-bitbucket/.